# Trying to find trending videos on Youtube

Tags: python, youtube

```
from pytrends.request import TrendReq
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pytube

# Create pytrends object
pytrends = TrendReq(hl='en-US', tz=360)

# Set up your keyword (you can customize this)
keyword = "trending videos"

# Set the country to India
pytrends.build_payload(kw_list=[keyword], geo='IN')

# Get trending search queries related to the keyword
trending_searches_df = pytrends.trending_searches()
print("Trending Searches in India:")
print(trending_searches_df)

# Get YouTube trending videos related to the keyword
youtube_trending_df = pytrends.trending_searches(pn='india')
print("\nYouTube Trending Videos in India:")
print(youtube_trending_df)

# Extract the actual video titles and video URLs from the search results
search_results = youtube_trending_df.iloc[:, 0].tolist()  # Get all search results

for query in search_results:
    print(f"\nTrending Video URLs for '{query}':")
    video_search = pytube.Search(query)
    videos = video_search.results
    for video in videos:
       print(f"Video Title: {video.title}")
       print(f"Video URL: {video.watch_url}\n")
```

The above code is generating the trending data using pytrends but it is showing the following warning:

```
Unexpected renderer encountered.
Renderer name: dict_keys(['reelShelfRenderer'])
Search term: Copenhagen vs Man United
Please open an issue at https://github.com/pytube/pytube/issues and provide this log output.
Unexpected renderer encountered.
Renderer name: dict_keys(['reelShelfRenderer'])
Search term: Copenhagen vs Man United
Please open an issue at https://github.com/pytube/pytube/issues and provide this log output.
Unexpected renderer encountered.
Renderer name: dict_keys(['reelShelfRenderer'])
Search term: Copenhagen vs Man United
Please open an issue at https://github.com/pytube/pytube/issues and provide this log output.
```

Help fix the issue, the code is working on other parts the issue is actually when it finds content related to reels (youtube shorts) - I found this https://github.com/pytube/pytube/pull/1642/commits/7a69ad5c0689c8d2e0c6047f12144c3a8f0a5ca2 but it's generating the same error, whichever way i tried to update the code.

Comment: What line produces these warnings?

Answer (score 0):

To fetch trending videos and reels from YouTube, you can use the YouTube Data API. Below is an example Python script using the google-api-python-client library to interact with the YouTube Data API.

Firstly, you need to install the required libraries:

```
pip install google-api-python-client google-auth-httplib2 google-auth-oauthlib
```

Now, you can use the following Python script:

```
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError

def get_youtube_trending(api_key, region_code='US', max_results=5):
    youtube = build('youtube', 'v3', developerKey=api_key)

    try:
        # Get trending videos
        trending_request = youtube.videos().list(
            part='snippet',
            chart='mostPopular',
            regionCode=region_code,
            maxResults=max_results
        )

        trending_response = trending_request.execute()
        trending_videos = []

        for item in trending_response['items']:
            video_data = item['snippet']
            video_id = item['id']
            title = video_data['title']
            channel_title = video_data['channelTitle']
            trending_videos.append({'title': title, 'channel': channel_title, 'video_id': video_id})

        return trending_videos

    except HttpError as e:
        print(f"An HTTP error occurred: {e}")
        return None

# Replace 'YOUR_API_KEY' with your actual YouTube Data API key
api_key = 'YOUR_API_KEY'

# Get trending videos (default: 5 videos)
trending_videos = get_youtube_trending(api_key)

# Display the trending videos
if trending_videos:
    print("Trending Videos:")
    for index, video in enumerate(trending_videos, start=1):
        print(f"{index}. Title: {video['title']}")
        print(f"   Channel: {video['channel']}")
        print(f"   Video ID: {video['video_id']}")
        print()
else:
    print("Failed to retrieve trending videos.")
```

Replace 'YOUR_API_KEY' with your actual YouTube Data API key.

To query reels, it may require some different API. Hope this helps, although it may be different from what you originally requested.

Comment: @Benjamin Loison, Great work! This really helped a lot of time. Very clean and great work. Good job man!